# How to match name and password from database remotely in Android

Tags: php, android, androidhttpclient

I want to fetch data of user from database on PHP server and save it to local database on button click. I am using following steps for this:

1. Check whether user is connected or not to internet
2. Take the name and password from `EditText` and send it to server

Then, from the server side:

1. If the user is registered, then send result 0
2. If the user is not registered, then send result 1
3. If the fields are empty, then send result -1

I am always getting -1 in the result, which says that my fields are empty. However, the when I check the log, it's not empty.

**Code**

```
MakeSong tsk1 = new MakeSong();
tsk1.execute(etName.getEditableText().toString(), etCountry.getEditableText().toString());

private class MakeSong extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {       
        //StringBuilder answer = new StringBuilder();
        String etmail = params[0];
        String etpass = params[1];

        Log.v("mail", etmail);
        Log.v("pass", etpass);

        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://example.com/try/index.php");

        try {
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("usermail", etmail));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userpass", etpass));

            httppost.setEntity((HttpEntity) new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httppost);

            Log.v("response", ""+response);

            InputStream inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            String bufferedStrChunk = null;
            while((bufferedStrChunk = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                stringBuilder.append(bufferedStrChunk);
            }

            return stringBuilder.toString();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        }

        return "hola";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        //do nothing
        //txtGen.setText(result);

        Log.v("GtSts", result);
    }
}
```

Here is the code I am using for server interaction which checks for the validation of user. I am fetching value by POST name which is not defined in the Android `EditText`.

What I want to know: is there any method in PHP POST which only checks the value I am sending, so that I just have to match those?

```
<?php
$path="../";
include "../config.php";
$run=false;
$toret = array('result' => "",'uid' => "",'kid' => "",'user' => "",'master' =>"");
if(!empty($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['password'])  ) {
    $demail=$_POST['name'];
    $dpass=md5($_POST['password']);
    $mail=$bd->execute("user_info",
            "*","ui_email_id='".$demail."'");
    if(count($mail)>0) {
        $passwrd=$bd->execute("master",
                "*","m_password='".$dpass."'");        
        if(count($passwrd)>0) {                
            $toret = array('result' => "1",'uid' => $mail[0]['ui_userid'],'kid_info' =>$kid,'user_info' => $mail,'master' =>$passwrd);
        } else { 
            $toret["result"]= "0";
        }
    } else { 
        $toret["result"]= "0";
    }
} else {
    $toret["result"]= "-1";
}                
header("Content-Type: application/json");
echo json_encode($toret);
?>
```

Comment: may be something wrong in your php script!

Comment: Exactly, your code seems fine, post your php code and add the php tag to your question !

Comment: i have edited plz check it i know  the error occurs on the POST  $demail=$_POST['name'];  $dpass=md5($_POST['password']); but how to sort out

Comment: Well if you look at java code your are passing `usermail` and `userpass` as **POST** while in php code your are expecting `name` and `password`!

Answer (score 0):

Use Json data to return your result it is more appropriate.

refer this . it is exact what you want : http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/